# Make displacement modifier line up with poles of object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, normals, displacement, height-map

Here is my problem. i have added a default bezier curve and used the screw modifier on the X axis to turn it into a teardrop/vase shape then converted it into a mesh. now if i apply a displacement modifier with a picture as displacement it places the displacement on the Z axis facing the side of the object,but i want it to face the x axis so that the center of my heightmap lines up with the tip of the bezier curve, like how a displacement on a uv sphere would line up with the 2 poles of the object.
i apologize for the quality of the picture but all it needs to show is how it displaces the object by default. if there is anything unclear about my question i'll gladly clarifiy. Thanks in advance! [image: bezier curve with screw modifier and displacement]

Comment: Have you tried using a **Mapping Node**?

Comment: i'd like to apply the transformation to the actual object, can you do that when making mesh displacement using nodes? and if so, how? edit: with that i mean, i want the change to remain, even if i switch back to using the non experimental version.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but using nodes to create a displacement has been a well supported feature for years, so you **don't** need an experimental version to use it (it will work in previous versions of Blender too). However, if you want to apply your displacement to the mesh, so that it actually changes the position of the vertices, you need to use a **Displacement Modifier**, which is a bit limited when compared to nodes. However, the **Displacement Modifier** lets you select the orientation or even a UV unwrap: you can just play with them